Normal of a given function through any given point
The setup for the problem:
This has bothered me for some time, but I have been trying to find a way to find any normal line through a given function that also travels through any other given point on the same real plane. I know that this won't work for all functions given any point on the real plane. I also know that there could be multiple normal lines for the function that can travel through a given point. However, if it can be calculated, how can that normal line be found?
Putting it into Math Lingo:
For any differentiable function $F$ and any point $P$, given that there exists at least one linear line $N$ that passes through $P$ and is normal to $F$, can the equation for $N$ be expressed in the form $N=m(x-a)+b$, or as an equation for vertical line?
Answer: Values of $F$ that pass through $P:=(x_{0},y_{0})$ and are normal to $F$ are solutions to the equation $F(x)-y_{0}=-\frac{1}{F'(x)}(x-x_{0})$, then can used to create the $i$th normal line equations $N_{i}=y_{i}-\frac{1}{F'(x_{i})}(x-x_{i})$
A few cherry picked examples of what I mean:

The function $f(x)=x^{2}$ has points $(5,-1)$ and $(-3,3)$ that lie on the same normal for $f$ through $f(1)$ which has the equation$N=f(1)-\frac{1}{f'(1)}(x-1)=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$but for the point $(10,2)$, $f$'s normal intersects $(10,2)$ from $f(2)$.
The function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ has no normal lines (at least on the real plane) that can travel through any points in the $3$rd quadrant, or points such as $(1,-1)$ and $(2,-2)$.Points like $(-1,5)$ and $(3,-3)$ do however have a normal line that passes through them, which is the normal line at $g(1)$.
The function $h(x)=sin(x)$ has at least 2 normal lines that pass through the point $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, one at $f(0)$, and one at $f(\frac{\pi}{2})$ (the slope would be infinite, or represented as a vertical line).

Follow-up Questions

Can the range of unreachable points from all normals of the function $F$ on the real plane be determined? For example, I know that the example function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ can't hit any of the points in the $3$rd quadrant, as well as a large region in the $4$th quadrant, but can that full range be calculated?
If some equation for the normal $N_{i}$ through $F$ and $P$ can be calculated, is there a way to determine if the calculated $N_{i}$ results in the shortest distance between $F$ and $P$ among the list of all normals $N_{k}$?

Desmos Graph for the Normal of $F(a)$

Not an answer, but you'll need $f$ to at least be differentiable to talk about being normal to its graph

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is true, I guess I did assume $F$ was differentiable. And as for being a specific problem, no I want this to be a general solution. Partly because I want to try to find a way to iterate a function that moves a point down that normal path onto a function $f_1$, then swap to travel down a normal path of a different function $f_2$, etc.

Expressing the equation of the normal line will involving the solution of a nonlinear equation involving $f$ and $f’$. This is obviously not possible to express in closed form in general.

I'm confused how the normal line would not be linear. I know that the equation to find the normal line would in fact be non-linear, but the normal line like shown in the $1$st example $N=f(1)-\frac{1}{f'(1)}(x-1)$ should always be linear.

View it from the opposite direction. Given a point $(x_0, y_0)$, the x-coordinate of the intersection point with the function must satisfy $y_0 - \frac{1}{f’(x)}(x-x_0)=f(x)$. The solution to this nonlinear equation in $x$ uniquely determines the slope and hence the equation of the line

For a given differentiable function $F(x)$, and a point $P:=(x_{0},y_{0})$, the equation $F(x)-y_{0}=-\frac{1}{F'(x)}(x-x_{0})$ does work! Thank you whpowell96!  I don't know how this has eluded me for so long, but that is the exact form that I had been looking for.

Since my curiosity still hasn't died, I tried tackling the second follow up question since it seemed more useful. However I'm struggling to even find the number of roots that would have to be checked, but after determining that, it would just be a distance calculation. I mean the answer seemed simple at first, just find a way to isolate x in the equation $F(x)-y_{0}=-\frac{1}{F'(x)}(x-x_{0})$, but since F can be any function, it makes it significantly harder. I first tried experimenting with derivatives along the parametric equation $g(t)=(t,f(t))$ to see where that went, but nothing so far.

Using the Equation above, I still haven't determined the answer to the other two follow up questions, but I made a better visual for solutions to the problem in Desmos. Honestly, this visual is really all I needed out of my original question, but I am still curious about the result of the other questions.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yq7tmec7qz
